# Does transform/opacity property invoke paint step in the browser conveyor

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, transform

Investigating how browser's render works I've noticed that in chrome dev tools with enabled flag `paint flashing` triggers paint step on changing `transform/opacity` property.

Look at these screenshots with code:

**Example 1 (`transform/opacity` property)**

```js
let elem = document.querySelector(".newLayer");
let count = 0;
function anim(){
  elem.style.transform = `translate(${count}px,0)`;
  /// interchangeable
  /// elem.style.opacity = `${count/500}`;
  if(count++ < 500)
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
  }
anim();
```

```css
.newLayer{
  position:relative;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="newLayer">I am a new Layer</div>
```

[image]

**Example 2 (`transform/opacity` property with `will-change`)**

```js
let elem = document.querySelector(".newLayer");
let count = 0;
function anim(){
  elem.style.transform = `translate(${count}px,0)`;
  /// interchangeable
  /// elem.style.opacity = `${count/500}`;
  if(count++ < 500)
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
  }
anim();
```

```css
.newLayer{
  will-change: transform;
  position:relative;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="newLayer">I am a new Layer</div>
```

[image]

It confuses me, because I've seen [this one](https://csstriggers.com/) and [this one](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/stick-to-compositor-only-properties-and-manage-layer-count) sources, they say when you're using `transform/opacity`, paint stage is ommited. So what is it? Why do we see paint in the first example, and don't in second? Which one is lying?

---

**Interesting one example with 2 paint operations:**

```js
let elem = document.querySelector(".newLayer");
let count = 0;
function anim(){
  elem.style.left = `${count}px`;
  if(count++ < 500)
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
  }
anim();
```

```css
.newLayer{
  position:relative;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="newLayer">I am a new Layer</div>
```

[image]

Yes, there is used property of positioning, but look at the paint operations, one big stripe and one small such as in example without `will-change`. What does it mean (I am speaking about paint with tiny stripe length)?

Is the tiny paint block related with raster threads, what about big one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither example is lying.

The browser minimises the number of layers it needs to composite together. It only creates a layer if it's given a reason to believe there'll be a benefit.

If you animate transform or opacity using CSS transitions, CSS animations, or web animations, the browser knows ahead of time that the element is animating in a way that might be optimised by creating a layer, so Chrome creates one for the duration of the animation.

If you animate using rAF, the browser doesn't have this foresight. `will-change` exists as a way to hint to the browser that it should create a layer for this element, depending on the changing property.

These are hints, and the browser isn't guaranteed to create a layer. There are other cases where some browsers create a layer, such as when another element needs to paint on top of a layer, and in the case of some other CSS like `transform: translateZ(…)`.

Comment: Hmm, so what about quote from csstriggers: `Changing "transform" does not trigger any geometry changes or painting, which is very good`. But there are examples that I presented that the painting trigger fires up if you using rAF. I feel myself cheated. Does text on csstriggers lie? Do I correct understand that often say about transform property in relation with css, but not with javascript?

Comment: "Lie" suggests it's a deliberate attempt to deceive, and I don't think there's proof of that. Regardless, we tend to say "tools not rules" - browsers change over time, so it's worth testing assumptions. That's what you did, and you found some assumptions to be wrong. My answer explains the reason behind your findings.

Comment: Sorry, english is not my native language, I expressed my thoughts by my language. Well, I wanted to say that an information in many sources is out of date, because no one source doesn't say about differences of optimization applying between css animation and js animation. I am glad that you responded to me and thanks for the answer.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you feel it answers your question (if it doesn't, let me know why)

Comment: I just waited answers from another participants of SO. Bounty was a kind of attracting attention. As I can see there are no others who would be give an answer. Therefore I accept your answer. By the way it would be nice if you did presentation like in 2018 about event loop but now about detailed render steps in the browser. Dreams :)

Comment: Could you take a look at following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53316338/what-is-the-difference-between-paint-and-rasterize-paint-in-chrome-dev-tools), it is very interesting but still has not the qualified answer

Comment: Why does the browser create a layer for an `opacity` animation but doesn't for a `background-color` one? It is said that updates of [`opacity`](https://csstriggers.com/opacity) property don't cause the paint stage but ones of [`background-color`](https://csstriggers.com/background-color) do. What's the difference between these properties?